# How to return with section value, if there more(approx.,10 to 20) sections in swift table view?

Tags: swift, uitableview, delegates

Here am creating 3 section in table view.

so in

numberOfRowsInSection --> am returning the count of each array in each section like below

```
    if(section == 0){

        return storedArr[section].count
    }
    else if(section == 1){

        return storedArr[section].count
    }
    else if(section == 2){

        return storedArr[section].count
    }
```

Is there any simple way to do it, If I have more sections in table view for ex: 10 to 20 section.

```
   var arr1:[String] = []
    var arr2:[String] = []
    var arr3:[String] = []

    var celebrityArr:[[String]] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        storedArr = [arr1, arr2, arr3]
    }


override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return storedArr.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if(section == 0){

            return storedArr[section].count
        }
        else if(section == 1){

            return storedArr[section].count
        }
        else if(section == 2){

            return storedArr[section].count
        }
        // and so on...... 
        return 0
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of handling for each `section` separately, write a generic code that will read from `storedArr`, i.e.

```
var storedArr = [[String]]()
```

**Number of sections** - total elements in `storedArr`

**Number of rows in section-x** - total elements in x'th element of `storedArr`

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.storedArr.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.storedArr[section].count
}
```

In this approach, no matter how many sections we have lets say `100 sections`, they all will be handled automatically.